# Selecting Every Combination of 50 Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, subset

I have an excel spreadsheet with around 600 rows and about 10 columns. Each row has a distinct Account Number. I want to create three subsets of 50 account number each that have around the same summation characteristics in one of the 10 other columns. So a subset of 50 rows that have the same average credit score and loan to value ratio as the entire set.

I was thinking if I look at every combination of 50 rows, I can calculate the values and see which subsets match the entire set. Is there a way to look at every subset of 50 rows in excel?

Comment: are you looking for all the combinations of 600 taken 50 at a time?

Comment: Checking the total for every combination like that will be incredibly resource intensive. You have to calculate the total for every combination and then find every combination twice again for all the rows left over. Sounds pretty intensive. How about ordering them according to the summation stat, then you start separating them like picking teams. The first group has first choice on the first round but last choice on the second one. Third group has last choice first round but first choice second round. Repeat until each group has 50 accounts or maybe until they have an ideal summation amount.